# Which metric to compare two probability density?

Tags: density-function, kullback-leibler, approximation, metric, divergence

I need to compare two distribution $p$ and $q$. But I don't have access to the distribution $p$, I want to approximate it by distribution $q$ that I construct iteratively by choosing design point. What metric to choose ? Kl divergence ? JS metric ?....

Comment: How can you compare to something that you don’t know?

Comment: The goal is to approximate it.

Comment: I understand. What I meant was that this situation is equivalent to trying to hit the bullseye on a dart board while blind-folded...

Comment: Are you wanting a true metric? The KL and JS divergences are not true metrics. However the JS distance (being the square root of the JS divergence) is a metric. Another common metric between two probability distributions is the Hellinger Distance.